# What is the proper way to submit hidden form information in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a site where a user can submit several different kinds of forms. I would like to include the type of form submitted (basic, advanced, other). I've read that using hidden fields with AngularJS is possible, but not recommended. Rather than finding a hack to solve the problem, I'd prefer to do things right. What is the proper way to submit information that does not need to be displayed to the user but should be included with a submission?

Here's the HTML for the form:

```
<form name="myForm">
<div class="control-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
</div>

<label>Description</label>
<textarea name="description"></textarea>
<button ng-click="editProject.save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

 <!--{{formselection}}-->

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ng-model the hidden fields are in the object memory context, only show the data to the user fill.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
      <div class="control-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="form.name">
      </div>

      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea name="description" ng-model="form.description"></textarea>
      <button ng-click="editProject.save(form)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> <!-- Pass the form to the method in controller-->

    </form>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.form = {
    hiddenField1: "anyValue",
    hiddenField2: "anotherValue"
  };

  $scope.editProject = {save: function(form){
    //http request given the form, this contain the name, description and the two hidden field

  }}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fjnGc4Q4f8ZfwhupkOdR